# $crawler->filter php script position

Tags: php, web-scraping, filter, web-crawler

I have 2 questions using `$crawler->filter`:

1- I want to get the data in the second div ( test2 )

```html
<div class="Ex1">test1</div>
<div class="Ex1">test2</div>
<div class="Ex1">test3</div>
```

2- same question but get just the first phrase i dont want to get span too meaning no include the balise children

```html
<div class="Ex2">test1</div>
<div class="Ex2">test2  <span>test2.2</span> </div>
<div class="Ex2">test3</div>
```

Edited :
I have a last question if you can help me i will be thankful ..

how can I get the data from class Ex3 but only the first or seconde one of them not both. exemple i want to get only "Test1"

```html
<div class="Ex3">
<div> Test1 </div>
<div> Test2 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: which library framework you are using ? Symfony ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the question first

```
$crawler->filter('.Ex1')->eq(1);
```

for second one you have to remove child elements first (span)

```
$crawler->filter('.Ex2 span')->each(function (Crawler $crawler) {
            foreach ($crawler as $node) {
                $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
            }
        });
```

and then have to get the value for element

```
echo $crawler->filter('.Ex2')->eq(1)->text();
```

for question 3rd last as you updated

to get first item

```
echo $crawler->filter('.Ex3')->children()->eq(0)->text();
```

to get 2nd item

```
echo $crawler->filter('.Ex3')->children()->eq(1)->text();
```